# How prove $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\cos{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2\le (n^2-1)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\sin{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality

let $n$ is odd number, and $a_{i},(i=0,1,\cdots,n-1)$ is  $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ arrangement,and $k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$

prove or disprove
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\cos{\dfrac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2\le (n^2-1)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\sin{\dfrac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2$$

My idea:
$$\Longleftrightarrow \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\cos{\dfrac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\sin{\dfrac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2\le n^2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}\sin{\dfrac{2k\pi i}{n}}\right)^2$$
This inequality is from my frend  ask me,maybe this is true,But I can't prove it.Thank you

Comment: Obviously false for $n>1$: Set $a_i=1, k=0$ then the LHS is $n^2$ but the RHS is zero.

Comment: Oh,I have edit,Thank you

Comment: The updated assumption that  $(a_{i})$ is permutation of $(0..n-1)$ is still too weak for $k=0$. Set $a_i=i,\,$ the LHS is $(n(n-1)/2)^2,\,$  but the RHS is still zero. I guess you must exclude $k=0$ for $n>1$.